# Return to Mainactivity if Firebase Database has no children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I"m stuck in one problem. My firebase structure is given in image where subject is the child value i get using intent extra on click from button

consider I have two buttons Button A  and Button B

when I press Button A then it will sent subject as string value of "Bhaktapur"  and now I have details of Bhaktapur in Recycleview but when I clcik Button B if it pass an string value "xyz" then I have no any value with data "xyz" then It should return to Mainactivity with Toast message " Not Found"

But The first one works fine and recycleview is updated with information but on second case I have progress Dialog keeps loading untill I cancel it.

Here is my code

```html
          dbreference = 
            
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books").child(subject);
          dbreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
          ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
          if (!data.exists()) {

                 progressDialog.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(SubjectBooks.this, "No books   
              found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Intent in = new Intent(SubjectBooks.this, 
              MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(in);
              finish();




          } else {

            final Books b1 = data.getValue(Books.class);
              //  Log.e("Value is ",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" 
              "+b1.getBauthor());
              //Log.e("Book"," received");


              child_count++;
              list.add(b1);
              staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

              progressDialog.dismiss();
          }

      }

  }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: I think you check if data exists before looping through all the results, since nothing inside the for loop will execute if there are no items in the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I clcik Button B if it pass an string value "xyz" then I have no any
>   value with data "xyz" then It should return to Mainactivity with Toast
>   message " Not Found"

Because no data found against `xyz`, `for loop` will not be executed neither `if-else`.As you are dismissing the progress bar inside `if-else`, it will keep showing indefinitely. So you've to check if `DataSnapshot` exist before `for loop` as follows

```
dbreference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      // TODO: handle the case where the data exists

      for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {

            final Books b1 = data.getValue(Books.class);
              //  Log.e("Value is ",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" 
              "+b1.getBauthor());
              //Log.e("Book"," received");

              child_count++;
              list.add(b1);
              staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              progressDialog.dismiss();

      }
    }
    else {
              // TODO: handle the case where the data does not yet exist
              progressDialog.dismiss();
              Toast.makeText(SubjectBooks.this, "No books   
              found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Intent in = new Intent(SubjectBooks.this, 
              MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(in);
              finish();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```